# Kotlin - conditional assign value in one line

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to conditional assign a value in one line in kotlin?

**Setup**

```
var foo: String

if (x != 0) {
  foo = x
}
```

**Goal**

```
// nothing is set if condition is false
foo = if (x != 0) x
```

**Not wanted**

```
// null is set if condition is false
foo = takeIf{ x != 0 }.let{ x }
```

Comment: Sure thing, `if (x != 0) foo = x` :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of doing this would be the following:

```kotlin
if (x != 0) foo = x
```

This is not always possible, because smart casting cannot be performed if there is a chance that another thread modifies the value between the null check in the assignment. This happens for instance if your `x` is a nullable `var` property on the class.

In that case, you have this option:

```kotlin
x?.let { foo = it }
```

Answer (score 9):

Is

```kotlin
foo = if (x != 0) x else foo
```

you want?

(Besides, you declared `var foo: String`, and the `x != 0` may indicate a `x: Int`, then you are not able to `foo = x`. Maybe a typo here.)

Comment: If `foo` is uninitialized it will not compile

Answer (score 5):

Sure thing

```
if (x != 0) foo = x
```